# Enable / Disable Razor layouts via routing

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I wonder if it's possible to wrap dynamically add layout to partial views based on routing.

For example:

- http://my.app.com/Controller/GetForm - returns a partial view
- http://my.app.com/Test/Controller/GetForm - returns the same partial view, but wrapped in _Layout.cshtml

The point here is that I don't want to create another view with duplicate functionality, but rather set Layout property dynamically.

Thanks.

Comment: Are both controller actions returning `PartialView(someModel)`?

Comment: GetForm would return `PartialView(someModel)`, yes. /Test route would take that PartialView and add layout to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**Action**

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    ViewBag.Layout = null;

    object layout;
    if (RouteData.Values.TryGetValue("layout", out layout)) {
        switch(layout.ToString())
        {
            case "Layout1":
                ViewBag.Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
                break;
            // ...
        }
    }

    return PartialView("Test");
}
```

**Markup**

```
@{
     Layout = ViewBag.Layout;
}

<div>This is the test page...</div>
```

**Routing config**

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }); // Parameter defaults

routes.MapRoute(
    "DefaultWithLayout", // Route name
    "{layout}/{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }); // Parameter defaults
}
```

Or just

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{layout}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", layout = UrlParameter.Optional, id = UrlParameter.Optional }); // Parameter defaults
```

Comment: This could work, but I'd like the process to be transparent to the controller. In any case, could you also provide the routing setup for you solution, please?

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom view result which checks route collection and executes PartialViewResult or ViewResult. And use it instead of View() or PartialView()

```
// constructor goes here which accepts model and view name

public override void ExecuteResult( ControllerContext context )
{
    ViewResultBase viewResult;
    // some check
    if( context.RouteData.Values || context.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl  )
    {
        viewResult = new ViewResult();
    }else
    {
        viewResult = new PartialViewResult();
    }
    viewResult.ExecuteResult( context );
}
```